# Requests to .NET Core Web API from Angular app (HttpClient) fail using the VSCode Debugger for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a launch.json configuration w/ the following:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Whenever I try to make a GET request to my ASP.NET Core Web API I receive 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

Whenever I try to make a POST requests it fails during the preflight OPTIONS request. OPTIONS https://localhost:5001/api/products/

Any idea why this is only happening when launching the Angular app through debugger for chrome using the above settings? If I run the site normally using ng serve all of the api calls using Angular Http client work fine.

Here is how I am making the request in my Angular service:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

  insertProduct(product: Product) {
    return this.http.post(this.productsUrl, product, httpOptions);
  }
```

I believe the issue stems from the following line in my Web API Startup.cs:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Is there anyway to tell the angular app when launching chrome debugger to run in ssl with a valid cert?

Comment: What is project type? Is it Angular Core template, or you develop Angular and web api separately? What is your `Startup.cs`? After launching project, could you access `https://localhost:5001/api/products/` from web browser? Is there any reproducebale project?

Comment: @edward The web api is an app.net core 2.1 Web API. The angular app is a standalone Angular app created with ng new, not dotnet new. When I launch the Web API project I am able to make successful calls to it the following ways: Postman and ng serve (the Angular app running normally). Let's say I want to debug the Angular app using Chrome Debugger in vscode. When I run this none of the API calls work. I have tried both https and http.

Comment: What is your `Startup.cs` in web api? Have you configured [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in web api?

Comment: @Edward Yes, I configured Cors to allow everything. It appears my issue is the following setting in my ASP.NET Core Web API Startup.cs: app.UseHttpsRedirection();. I am assuming when running Angular through the Chrome debugger it is loading in http:// localhost/4200 without a valid cert probably. It is strange that when running ng serve it works. Maybe something is cached or stored in the browser that is not stored when running chrome debugger. Since chrome debugger opens a window almost as if it is an incognito tab.

Comment: @Edward As a temporary solution I have commented out the app.UseHttpsRedirection(); line in my Startup.cs Configure method. This makes it so calls to http:// localhost:5000 work without redirecting to https. In the angular app I simply had to change the api url to http: // localhost:5000/api/products. Even though this works it would be nice to someday figure out how to use https with the web api and still call it through the Angular app without it denying me.